# Invite friends via facebook - Is it possible?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, message

According to latest Facebook SDK ([V 2.0+](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends)), "This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request." But my requirement is sending private message to my facebook friends to let them know that I am using this particular app. Is there any way to achieve this feature. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Graph API v2.0`, `/me/friends` returns a person's friends who also use the app.

You can use `/me/invitable_friends`. But `/me/invitable_friends` only available to apps classified as Games

more info :  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/invitable_friends

Comment: But my app is not a Game. It is a shopping app. Any chances for such an app?

Comment: I think you can't. Don't know whether any server side implementation is helpful in this case.. I mean something like "Facebook Connect PHP Toolkit"

Answer (score 0):

This article explains exactly how to invite friends (in a Game or App): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

**Games on Facebook Canvas** (apps.facebook.com/yournamespace): [Invite](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.2) Dialog and [invitable_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/invitable_friends)

**Any other App**: [Message](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share) and [Send](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog) Dialogs (depending on platform)

**In your case (iOS platform), you can only use the Message Dialog.**

Comment: Thank you for this vakuabke information. I saw something like this in the above message sending tutorial - "The Message Dialog requires that the user has the native Facebook Messenger for iOS app installed on their device. Because the Message Dialog can only be presented when the native Facebook Messenger for iOS app is installed". So I won't be able to present a custom UI for my feature, just navigate to Messanger app is the only available solution. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: you can present a custom UI too, but you would need to authorize the user with the "publish_actions" permission and you would need to go through a review process with that permission on facebook.

Comment: But how can I get a friend's id to which I have to send message?

Comment: ah, forget about that. it would be needed for posts on your own wall. but you can´t send messages to a friend with that - the message dialog is the only option.